# Do COBE, WMAP, and Plack have design flaws?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmic-microwave-background, blackbody

MRI expert Pierre-Marie Robitaille on the design flaws of COBE, WMAP, & Planck and the violation Kirchhoff's Law:

Here are his talks:

**[Pierre-Marie Robitaille: The Cosmic Microwave Background](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8ijbu3bSqI)**

**[Pierre-Marie Robitaille: On the Validity of Kirchhoff's Law](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Hstum3U2zw)**

Robitaille holds the world record for highest resolution MRI imaging.

An interesting point he makes is that cosmological sources would not vary over time, yet the COBE, WMAP, and Plank data are highly variable.

Here are his papers detailing the design flaws of COBE, WMAP, and Planck:

Robitaille P.-M.
WMAP: A Radiological Analysis
http://www.ptep-online.com/index_files/2007/PP-08-01.PDF

Robitaille P.-M.
COBE: A Radiological Analysis
http://www.ptep-online.com/index_files/2009/PP-19-03.PDF

Robitaille P.-M.
The Planck Satellite LFI and the Microwave Background: Importance of the 4K Reference Targets
http://www.ptep-online.com/index_files/2010/PP-22-02.PDF

Comment: If you are particularly concerned about the variability of the CMB, you should take a look at http://www.esa.int/spaceinimages/Images/2013/03/Planck_WMAP_comparison, where you can see for yourself that it hasn't perceptibly changed.

Comment: A quick google search shows that Robitaille turned into a crackpot around 2000, and he's been spewing complete nonsense ever since. Here's an example from 2002, when he spent $100,000 on a New York Times ad to promote his garbage: http://www.nytimes.com/2002/03/19/us/ripples-in-ohio-from-ad-on-the-big-bang.html

Comment: Robitaille is involved with the Thunderbolts Project, which is basically a bunch of lunatics led by a couple of old guys who have no idea what they are talking about. Just a month ago I read an article written by one of their senior members; he was attempting to explain the Pioneer Anomaly in terms of Electric Universe predictions, and was apparently unaware that the source of the Pioneer Anomaly had already been discovered **over two years earlier**. The entire organization is deluded and out of touch with reality, and I wouldn't be surprised of Robetaille was any different.